# Real life application of Conway's Game of life

Tags: cellular-automata

Does Conway's Game of Life has any real life application?

I mean applications that are used today.
If so, please add references, because I couldn't find anything, except for some hypothetical applications.

Comment: Of course not. ${}$

Comment: I'm afraid too, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Of course: Its application is to entertain, fascinate and inspire the spectator.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Game of Life on Triangular Tessellations: Image recovery, as proposed [here](http://i-rep.emu.edu.tr:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11129/3618/saadatmohammad.pdf?sequence=1):

[image]